# Paypal recurring profile charge trial amount for first eight month

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

I need to create a recurring billing profile in paypal manager in which I can provide the discount for first 4-9 month. for example:

- User registered to website on dated Jan 01, 2017

- I want to provide this user a trial period for 9 month in which I will charge a minimum amount for example $1 per month. After 9 month I want to charge this user a normal amount for example $50 per month.

- I know I can provide one month trial period but please also let me know if I can provide 4 month or 9 month trial period and charge my users minimum amount (discount amount) per month during trial period.

Update:
Below is my full code which I used to setup recurring payment in paypal manager.

```
$request = array("VENDOR" => "######",
"PARTNER" => "paypal",
"USER" => "######",
"PWD" => "######",
"TRXTYPE" => "R",
"ACTION" => "A",
"PROFILENAME" => "######",
"START" => "06222017",
"PAYPERIOD" => "MONT",
"TERM" => "0",
"COMMENT1" => "######",
"COMMENT2" => "Dealership Description",
"RECURRING" => "Y",
"COMPANYNAME" => "######",
"TENDER" => "C",
"ACCT" => "4111111111111111",
"AMT" => "2.00",
"EXPDATE" => "0619",
"FIRSTNAME" => "######",
"LASTNAME" => "######",
"STREET" => "######",
"CITY" => "Feltham",
"COUNTRY" => "US",
"STATE" => "###",
"ZIP" => "231321",
"EMAIL" => "######",
"SHIPTOFIRSTNAME" => "######",
"SHIPTOLASTNAME" => "######",
"SHIPTOSTREET" => "######",
"SHIPTOCITY" => "Feltham",
"SHIPTOCOUNTRY" => "US",
"SHIPTOSTATE" => "#####",
"SHIPTOZIP" => "231321",
"OPTIONALTRX" => "S",
"OPTIONALTRXAMT" => "1.00");
```

With the above code I can successfully created a recurring profile with optional transaction (trial period amount) in paypal manager. 
I insert "TRIALTOTALBILLINGCYCLES" in above code but still have no luck. Please let me know if you have any solution.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Set the NVP as follows:

```
&TRIALBILLINGPERIOD=Month
&TRIALBILLINGFREQUENCY=1
&TRIALAMT=1
&TRIALTOTALBILLINGCYCLES=9
&BILLINGPERIOD=Month
&BILLINGFREQUENCY=1
&AMT=50.00
&CURRENCYCODE=USD
.....other parameters here....
```

"&TRIALTOTALBILLINGCYCLES" decides the number of trial months/years.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I insert "TRIALTOTALBILLINGCYCLES" in my code but still have no luck. Please let me know if you have any solution.